# Update all date fields of my mongodb collection with one hour minor

Tags: node.js, mongodb, timezone

i was having a timezone problem on my node js API, cause it was save my data with one hour plus in the mongo db collection, so now i need to update all the date fields in mycollection with one hour minor. I just set the right timezone on the node js API and for the new data the problem is solved, but for old data i need to update with the (actual stored date - 1 hour). How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
db.demo.find({date : { $exists : true } ).forEach(function(document) {
db.demo.update(
   { _id     : document._id }
 , { $set : { date : new Date(document.date.getTime() - 3600000) }}
);
});
```